# How can I compare cells in different rows and insert-right if lower cell if not the same?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I compare cells in two rows and and match the lower cell value to the upper cell value, if the two are different?  Here is some the same data I am working with and what I hope to see after the code runs.

Before:

```
[ID_GLOBAL], [ID_UNIQUE], [ID_REAL], [ID_1], [ID_2], [GAS_ADJ], [OBJ_ADJ]
[ID_GLOBAL], [ID_UNIQUE], [ID_REAL], [GAS_ADJ], [OBJ_ADJ]
```

After:

```
[ID_GLOBAL], [ID_UNIQUE], [ID_REAL], [ID_1], [ID_2], [GAS_ADJ], [OBJ_ADJ]
[ID_GLOBAL], [ID_UNIQUE], [ID_REAL], NULL AS [ID_1], NULL AS [ID_2], [GAS_ADJ], [OBJ_ADJ]
```

I think the code will basically look like this, but I haven't gotten the insert-right working properly.

```
Sub CompareCellsDiffRows()
Dim bothrows  As Range, i As Integer

Set bothrows = Selection

With bothrows
    For i = 1 To .Columns.Count
        If Not StrComp(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(2, i), vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
            ' magic happens here
        End If
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

As you may have guessed, I'm dealing with hundreds of fields in several tables and trying to Union everything together, so all these field names have to match up in the correct order.

Thanks.

Comment: everything in your example is upper case? Where is the lower case portion of your problem? Or did I misread hmm

Comment: Will the top always have more columns or could your rows just as easily be reversed?

Comment: Yes, the field names are always uppercase.  So far, I have only seen the top having more fields.  I'm sure it's easier to code if you go with that assumption, right.

Comment: will there be a case in which a field name in row 1 is not in row 2 and also a field name in row 2 is not in row 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming, as per your example, that the first row is the one that will be always complete.

```
Sub CompareRowDifferences()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim i, LastColumn As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Transposed Fields")
LastColumn = sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column

With sht
    For i = 1 To LastColumn
        If StrComp(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(2, i), vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then
            .Cells(2, i).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            .Cells(2, i).Value2 = "NULL AS " & .Cells(1, i).Value2
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Hope it helps

Regarding your second question (if they are not ordered) and assuming always that the first line is the ones that rules...

```
Sub CompareRowDifferences()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim i, j, LastColumn As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Transposed Fields")
LastColumn = sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
j = 0

With sht
    For i = 1 To LastColumn
        Test = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range _
          (Cells(2, i), Cells(2, LastColumn + j)), .Cells(1, i).Value2)
        If Test >= 1 Then
            .Cells(2, i).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            .Cells(2, i).Value2 = .Cells(1, i).Value2
        Else
            .Cells(2, i).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            .Cells(2, i).Value2 = "NULL AS " & .Cells(1, i).Value2
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Next i
    Range(Cells(2, LastColumn), Cells(2, LastColumn + j)).ClearContents
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a ton David.  This is fantastic!!

Answer (score 1):

This procedure identifies and uses the row with a higher number of fields (i.e. no-empty cells), and uses it as *"model"* to update the other row regardless of the position of the fields in the other row.

```
Sub Headers_Comparison(rInput As Range)
Dim aOut As Variant, aSrc As Variant, aTrg As Variant
Dim bMatch As Byte, bRow As Byte, b As Byte


    With WorksheetFunction

        Rem Validate Fields in Rows
        If .CountA(rInput.Rows(1)) > .CountA(rInput.Rows(2)) Then
            bRow = 2
            aSrc = .Transpose(.Transpose(rInput.Rows(1).Value2))
            aTrg = .Transpose(.Transpose(rInput.Rows(2).Value2))

        Else
            bRow = 1
            aSrc = .Transpose(.Transpose(rInput.Rows(2).Value2))
            aTrg = .Transpose(.Transpose(rInput.Rows(1).Value2))

        End If

        aOut = aTrg
        For b = 1 To UBound(aSrc)
            bMatch = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            bMatch = .Match(aSrc(b), aTrg, 0)
            On Error GoTo 0
            aOut(b) = IIf(bMatch > 0, vbNullString, "NULL AS ") & aSrc(b)

    Next: End With

    rInput.Rows(bRow).Value = aOut

    End Sub
```

It should be called in this manner:

```
Call Headers_Comparison(rSel)    'update with required range
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks so much EEM.

Answer (score -1):

I think I just figured it out!

```
Sub CompareRowDifferences()

Dim i As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastColumn As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Transposed Fields")
LastColumn = sht.UsedRange.Columns(sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column

For i = 1 To LastColumn
    If Not StrComp(sht.Cells(1, i), sht.Cells(2, i), vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
        ' magic happens here
        Set Rng = sht.Cells(2, i)
        Rng.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        sht.Cells(2, i).Value = "NULL AS " & sht.Cells(1, i).Value

    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

This seems to work.  Although, this is a pretty simple solution.  I understand it would be much more complex if the order of names the lower row changed.  This works ONLY because the names in row 2 match the names in row 1, there are just fewer names.  I would love to see what the code would look like if the order of the row 2 names was switch around, compared to the row 1 names.

Comment: my answer works when the order of the names is different and also when there are few names in the first row.